# What is the name of the thermodynamic potential $U - \mu N $?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology

It is the exponent of the terms in the summation for grand canonical partiton function. What is its name?

Comment: There isn't really a name for it. Since the internal energy is $U_{GC}=TS-pV+\mu N$ in the grand-canonical potential, $U_{GC}-\mu N = TS-pV\equiv U_C$ is simply the internal energy of the canonical ensemble (i.e. with a fixed number of particles).

Comment: The question is ill-posed. in the grand canonical partition function you do not have the thermodynamic energy $U$ but the Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$, which is not a thermodynamic potential, so even $H- \mu N$ is not a thermodynamic potential. If you are referring to $-k_BT$ the $log$ of the gran canonical partition function, that is a thermodynamic potential often called *grand potential* and it is equal to $PV$.